# wp-config.php not affecting my site

Tags: wp-admin, installation, wp-config, backup

I just received a backup of my WP site from the developer that includes the WP files and the database .sql file. I'm trying to install it on my server, but my WP build is ignoring `wp-config.php`. When I access `domain.com/wp-admin` I get `Internal Server Error`:

#### Steps I've taken:

1. I uploaded the ZIP file with all WP files to the server and unzipped. Everything is now on the server, including `/wp-admin`, `/wp-content`, `/wp-includes` and so on...
2. I created a new database with names that match the DB_NAME and DB_USER from `wp-config.php` below (except for the prefix).
3. I [uploaded the `.sql` file](https://css-tricks.com/moving-a-wordpress-site/) to the new database. Database is now populated.
4. I [updated `wp-config.php`](https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/) so the database fields match my database. I had to update the prefix `xxxx` because it has to start with my hosting service's username. I kept the rest the same, including the password.

```
define( 'DB_NAME', 'xxxx_dbname' );       // Only updated prefix xxxx
define( 'DB_USER', 'xxxx_dbuser' );       // Only updated prefix xxxx
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', '[userPassword]' ); // I set the DB user password to match this one
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8' );
define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );
$table_prefix = 'gw48ep_';    // This matches all tables on DB
```

I also reset all the 'AUTH_KEY's and salts to `'put your unique phrase here'`.

When I visit my site, the content displays fine. But when I visit `domain.com/wp-admin` or `/wp-login.php`, I get:

> Internal Server Error. The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.`

I tried deleting `wp-config.php` and it doesn't change anything. It's like this file isn't being read by my WP installation. I also tried enabling debugging with

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
```

but my `error_log` file only shows old logs from two weeks ago.

What step am I missing? It's like my `wp-config.php` isn't even being read at all! Nothing I change on it makes any difference.

Comment: Was this backup running at the exact same URL you are trying to run it on? If the developer was working on localhost or a staging site, then if they did not use a migration plugin, the URLs throughout the database are trying to reference localhost and in fact need to be referencing your production domain. You can look in the `wp_options` table for two of the most common URL settings and see if those are correct - but in addition to those there will be lots of other references to the URL which in many cases are serialized, so just changing in the DB won't solve, you'd need to use a plugin.

Comment: @WebElaine Thanks for bringing that up! The URL is the same, we just changed from one hosting service to another. So the IP is new, but the domain hasn't changed. However, I thought something would change if I delete `wp-config.php` from the server, but they both give me `500 Server error` It must be another configuration file that's breaking the Wordpress build.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the DNS settings have propagated? Many times when you switch hosts it takes 2 or 3 days for the domain to fully point to the new host, so it could be trying to reach the old host or partly the old and partly the new (like seeing files on the old host but database on the new) while that's in progress.

Comment: @WebElaine Interesting! The old IP started with `104.153.xxx.xxx`, and I can confirm on my browser's Network tab that my HTML and assets are being fetched from the new IP `162.241.xxx.xxx:443` (It took about 5 hours for DNS propagation). However, I don't know how to check which database IP is being used. I thought they would be one and the same?

Comment: You could make a small change to a post or page directly in the new database, and then see whether that change appears on that post or page. If so, it's using the correct - new - database. If not, it's pulling from the old. (In phpMyAdmin, go to the `prefix_posts` table, edit a published Post or Page's `post_content`, and be sure to clear any caching plugins before checking.)

Comment: Internal Server Error is just a generic message that says look in the PHP error log or the server error log to find the actual error message. Can you look in your PHP error log to find what the message is? Right now the only information we have is that something went wrong and Apache/Nginx gave the blanket error code of 500, which isn't very useful on its own